# How to find docker URL?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-agent, jenkins-docker

[image]I have used this image https://hub.docker.com/r/bibinwilson/jenkins-slave/
and created container with below comments
`docker run -d -p 80:80 bibinwilson/jenkins-slave`

Comment: Where is your docker instance running? And using docker for mac/windows/linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created Docker host authentication with docker certificates  ,now its working fine

Answer (score 2):

If your host needs to allow connections from a jenkins instance hosted on a different machine, you will need to open up the TCP port. This can be achieved by editing the docker config file and setting (for example)

DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

The docker configuration file location will depend your system, but it is likely to be /etc/init/docker.conf, /etc/default/docker or /etc/default/docker.io)

Comment: please share the configuration file location in windows machine

Comment: It should be located at 'C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json'

Comment: No,above location not exist in my machine but i have found config.json in below location 
%Userprofile%\.docker\machine\machines\default
is this our config file?

Comment: I am not sure about this, but you can give it a try